# (SOLVED) auglag constrained optimization with multivariate objective and inequality constraint

Tags: r, optimization, parameter-passing

UPDATE (SOLVED): It's times like these I hate R. Over a day later, turns out that the variables needed to be defined in my objective and inequality functions in the same order as passed to auglag. I actually found the fix after experiencing the same problem in nloptr, so hopefully this helps someone someday!

I'm try to estimate the below objective using auglag and get the following error (with no output)

"Error in hin(par, ...) : argument "b" is missing, with no default"

I have shared the code below. All matrices are conformable. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Also, I did look at examples but could find no multivariate examples.

```
# WLS objective function 


wls_obj <- function(x, b, y, w){
  e <- y - x %*% b
  obj <- t(e) %*% w %*% e
  return(obj)
}


# constrained WLS minimization 

b <- as.matrix(rep(1,7))
x <- as.matrix(data.frame(rep(1,nrow(x)),x))

hin <- function(x,b){
  hin <- x %*% b
  return(hin)
}

model <- auglag(par=b,fn=wls_obj,hin=hin,c(x=x,y=y,w=w))`
```

I am trying to minimize the objective over b, given the constraint that x%*%b gte 0. I was expecting a constrained solution in b.